# How to send email for payment receipt to customer from Stripe using c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

The Stripe is configured with mvc application. but need to send email receipt to customer after successful payment done. If not wrong this can do after webhook event gathered. but couldn't find exact code or api for email payment receipt in c#. any guidelines please.

**Edited:**
 Sorry, I thought someone knew about stripe...
my code is

```
                        var myCustomer = new StripeCustomerCreateOptions();
                        // set these properties if it makes you happy
                        myCustomer.Email = "email@me.com";
                        myCustomer.Description = "test: email@me.com";
                        myCustomer.CardNumber = "4242424242424242";
                        myCustomer.CardExpirationYear = "2016";
                        myCustomer.CardExpirationMonth = "10";                           
                        myCustomer.CardName = "Red Swan";               
                        myCustomer.CardCvc = "223";  
                        myCustomer.PlanId = "testPremium";                        
                        myCustomer.Quantity = 1;                            

                        var customerService = new StripeCustomerService();
                        StripeCustomer stripeCustomer = customerService.Create(myCustomer);

                        var chargeService = new StripeChargeService();
                        var stripeCharge = chargeService.Create(myCharge);
```

This code creates the customer on Stripe as well as performs the payment aganist the plan id that provided... but for sending the mail (generated payment receipt by stripe) to this customer, I need guidelines for code. 
I tried for code :

```
 var myCharge = new StripeChargeCreateOptions
                            {
                                CustomerId = stripeCustomer.Id,
                                Currency = "gbp",
                                Amount=1000,
                               ReceiptEmail="customer@email.com"
                            };
                            var chargeService = new StripeChargeService();
                            var stripeCharge = chargeService.Create(myCharge);
```

but not working.

Comment: what code do you have? what have you tried? you're not giving nearly enough information for anyone to help you

Comment: please find my edited.

Comment: Any updates on this topic? or at least guide where i can get answer?

Comment: I can read this "If you have Stripe email receipts enabled, the description on a charge or invoice item will appear on the email receipt that is sent to your customer." on the page here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#metadata   thought it might help you